# Constructing my Python package so the import statements work properly

Tags: python, package

I have a local package with the structure below

```
foo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        bar.py
    auth/
        auth_file.txt
    setup.py
```

`bar.py` defines two classes, which are the classes I'm now trying to use elsewhere. I've successfully installed the package via `pip install -e foo`.

The following code works:

```
from foo.bar import baz

_baz = baz()
```

This, however, does not work. The error returned is that `foo` does not have the attribute `bar`.

```
import foo

_baz = foo.bar.baz()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `foo` doesn't automatically import its subpackages and modules. It does automatically import `foo.__init__`. You either have to explicitly `import foo.bar` or put the import of `bar` into `foo.__init__`.